# Passing all fields from child page to parent using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a small problem regarding passing values from one page two another

There are two pages in (Page 1 & Page 2). In page1 there is add button to open page 2 . Page two has three fields namely name , phone & email id & ones submit button. When User clicks the Submit button on page 2 , json object needs to be mapped so that I can save details from Page 1 itself. This is required as reference of page 1 needs to be stored in page 2

Kindly help for the same

Comment: Use cookies or localStorage

Comment: var contactList=[{"name":"","email":"","mobile":""}];

Comment: is page 2 opened instead of page 1, or is it a "popup" or an iframe ... devil is in the details

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify() and store the data in local storage.

```
var a=[{x:"2"},{y:"3"},{z:"4"}];
var b=JSON.stringify(a);
window.localStorage.setItem("credential",b);
```